# My terminal does not exit when I keyboard interrupt (Ctrl + C) due to multithreading. Any Fixes?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, input, try-catch, keyboardinterrupt

I have seen this question on stack overflow before but it does not seem to work and the solution was 4 years old so maybe it was outdated?

My code is below and it works fine, but when I want to stop the program to test it for bugs it constantly breaks the terminal by printing the last few statements while preventing me from typing.

Any fixes to this issue?

```
from threading import Thread
import time

try:

    uInput = ""

    counter = 3

    thread_running = True


    def passwordInputting():
        global counter
        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_time <= 10:
            uInput = input()
            if uInput != "password":
                print("Incorrect Password.", counter, "tries remaining.")
                counter -= 1
                                    
            else:
                # code for if password is correct
                break

    def passwordTimer():

        global thread_running
        global counter

        start_time = time.time()
        last_time = time.time()

        # run this while there is no input or user is inputting
        while thread_running:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if time.time() > last_time + 1:
                print("Counter:", int(time.time() - start_time))
                last_time = time.time()
            if time.time() - start_time >= 10:
                if uInput == "password":
                    continue
                else:
                    if counter > 0:
                        print("Incorrect Password.", counter, "tries remaining.")
                        counter -= 1
                        start_time = time.time()
                        
                    else:
                        # code for when no more tries left
                        break
                    
    timerThread = Thread(target=passwordTimer)
    inputThread = Thread(target=passwordInputting)

    timerThread.start()
    inputThread.start()

    inputThread.join() # interpreter will wait until your process get completed or terminated
except:
    print("Keyboard Manual Interrupt. Ege is Gay")
thread_running = False

print("Program Finished")
exit()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? WHAT IS THIS???

Comment: Its multithreading and I am trying to figure how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writing a line of code before starting the threads setting daemon to True fixes the issue.

```
    timerThread = Thread(target=passwordTimer)
    inputThread = Thread(target=passwordInputting)

    timerThread.daemon = True
    inputThread.daemon = True 

    timerThread.start()
    inputThread.start()

    inputThread.join() # interpreter will wait until your process get completed or terminated
```

Those lines enable you to press ctrl + C to end the program at will and use the terminal again.